# у DIscord бота не меняется статус

Tags: python, discord.py

Сразу к коду:

```py
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json

EnableStatus = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="adm.", intents=discord.Intents.none())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот запущен...")
    while True:
        try:
            t = requests.get(f"https://api.scpslgame.com/serverinfo.php?id=24764&key={api_key}&players=true").text
            data = json.loads(t)
            f = open("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Папка\\data.json", "w")
            f.write(t)
            f.close()
            ans = data["Servers"][0]["Players"]
            totalPlayers = int(ans.split('/', 1)[0])
            totalSlots = int(ans.split('/', 1)[1])
            if totalPlayers == 0:
                stat = discord.Status.idle
                ans = 'Сервер пустует :('
            elif totalPlayers == totalSlots:
                stat= discord.Status.dnd
                ans = 'Сервер полон!'
            else:
                stat= discord.Status.online
            print(ans)

            await bot.change_presence(status = stat,activity=discord.Game(name=ans))   

            waitTime = data["Cooldown"] + 10
            await asyncio.sleep(waitTime)
        except:
            print('Что-то пошло не так...')
            stat = discord.Status.dnd
            ans = 'Сервер выключен!'
            await bot.change_presence(status = stat,activity=discord.Game(name=ans))
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
bot.run("token")
```

Как бы возникает **вопрос** в чём проблема? Текст статуса меняется, а сам статус **нет**... Статус всегда остаётся "*онлайн*", хотя по коду должен меняться...
https://imgur.com/a/4Fz0Jtn

Бот по одной игре работает корректно, а по другой нет xd
https://imgur.com/a/imBsGBd